# Duplicate questions from the same user should be punished more harshly than duplicate questions from different users

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Shouldn't a user who is repeating the same question in different ways be punished more harshly than somebody who just didn't know how to properly word the question they were asking? Sometimes it would require knowledge inherent to knowing the answer already in order to realize that the question they were asking was a duplicate question.

For example, I posted a question about CUDA programming to ask why my result wasn't returning the appropriate answer: [Why is my cuda sum program not working on the device end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860461/why-is-my-cuda-sum-program-not-working-on-the-device-end?noredirect=1#comment55492757_33860461)

The answer had to do with the way I was compiling it. Unless I knew that that specific problem might arise from that particular problem with compilation, I would not have been able to know that it was a compilation error in the first place.

Somebody who has my specific problem with that same compilation error might stumble upon my post and be redirected to the appropriate answer, which would be a duplicate of another problem other people have had. Surely this is more valuable to the community than somebody who spams the same question in order to abuse the "most recently asked questions" system.

Comment: I'm a little unclear. Are you asking for a lightening of the penalty for certain questions from what exists at present, or a heavier penalty on the opposite category of questions than what exists at present? There doesn't seem to be any room for the former, given that your question has no downvotes and (as a dupe) will not count toward question-banning, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Why should duplicate questions suffer any punishment at all?  Questions that meet the downvote criteria should be downvoted whether they are duplicates or not, duplicates can be useful as additional signposts to an answer and **your** question has suffered no punishment. It's already easier to close as a duplicate if the same user asks the same question because you can close all but one as duplicates without the initial question having an answer. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Are you sure it doesn't count towards question-banning? I didn't get the message, "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more" until I posted the question I referenced above. None of my questions have a negative score, but 2 of them were marked as duplicate.

Personally I don't think duplicate questions should be a reason to ban users from asking questions, unless the user is spamming the same question in different ways to abuse the system.

Comment: @JoshBreece: It appears I was mistaken, although I don't understand why dupes would count toward the Q-ban.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - They shouldn't be not directly.  Most duplicates have little to no up votes though.

Comment: @JoshBreece - The reason you are being warned is because out of 7 questions you have only 2 upvotes.  Any questions you have deleted or have been deleted by the community also count against you.

Comment: @Ramhound: It does appear though, especially from a number of developer comments, that dupes are taken into account roughly as though they were closed questions -- that is, it is worse to have an upvoted dupe than to have an equally upvoted unclosed question, all else being equal.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - If a question cannot receive question, they are Indirectly, they are still considered closed so that makes sense.  I think Josh's warning is mainly connected to the fact he only recieved 2 upvotes, which means he has at least 3 downvotes on content only 10K reptuation can see. ( 20 ( upvotes ) - 6 ( 3 x 2 downvotes ) = 14 total )

Comment: @Ramhound: Deleted posts do not count for rep in either direction; the actual rep is 1 + 15 (3 question upvotes) - 2 (1 question downvote).

Comment: @NathanTuggy - You are indeed correct.

Answer (score 6):

If I see the same question asked again by the same user then I vote to close it as a duplicate and downvote it.

I *think* both feed into question ban calculations and I think that stops users doing it again in a hurry.

I don't think any new functionality is required.

Comment: I got the message, "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more," despite the fact that I have never asked the same question twice, and none of my posts have a negative score. I got the message only after posting my above referenced post, which means I must have gotten the warning because it got marked as duplicate. I'm not suggesting a harsher penalty for spam questions, but rather a lighter penalty for "duplicate" questions that are not actually spam.

Comment: @JoshBreece You're probably getting that because none of your posts are attracting upvotes.

Comment: @JoshBreece your rep of 14 on SO, compared to the vote total of your Q & A, indicates that you may have gotten some down votes, as well as up votes. Your **net** total may be 0 or higher, but you still got down voted, triggering the warning.

Comment: @cde You can get banned for asking questions that receive an overall neutral reception?

Comment: @JoshBreece maybe. It weighs harder on new users who haven't made other good contributions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans